Struggling in Excel subtractions
I'm struggling with an Excel, forgot the basic Excel at all.
What I'd like to do is, considering that I have: 1848.46 EUR placed in H2 cell.
Within range of G3:G9 cells that currently contains value of "НЕТ", once i change the cell value within that range to "ДА", I have to do like this: H2 - (H2:H9) only if within G column the value equals to "ДА".
For instance, in case if in G4 cell contains value of "ДА", then I have to H2 - H4.
If I change G5 cell value to "ДА" then I have H2-H5.
Any ideas? Or I'm dumb on explaining what I want to do? :-D Sorry about it.
What I tried already, is the IF formula with multiple IFs in false case. It didn't work to me. Tried COUNTIF ecc... still struggling.


One way is this:
= H2 - SUMIF(G3:G9, "ДА", H3:H9)

The SUMIF part will look at the values in column G which contain "ДА" and then sum the corresponding values from column H. You then need to subtract those from H2 to get the answer you need.
